# Why is a documented security setting missing from the IBM Traveler server configuration page?

Tags: ibm, lotus-notes

I've set up an IBM Traveler server to allow certain users access to their mail from their mobile devices, using IBM's mobile app (IBM Verse).

The "Allow only approved applications and built in secure viewers to access attachments" setting seems to be missing from the web configuration page (LotusTraveler.nsf) despite being mentioned in [online documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYRPW_9.0.1/EnablingAttachmentSecuritySettings.dita?lang=en).

The setting is on the page when you load it without JavaScript enabled, and enabling the setting in the postdata array doesn't result in an error, but also doesn't enable the setting.

Comment: The server is Called "IBM Traveler server", not "IBM Verse server", but please tell us which version you installed. I have this option in `Preferences - security - Apple - Apple mail`, so please tell us, where you searched for it...

Comment: It's version 9.0.1, the setting is documented to be in Preferences - Security - Apple - IBM Verse (and it appears there when Javascript is disabled.) the page title and all of the information on the server refers to it as IBM Traveler [Server]. (They're renaming it is my guess)

Comment: sorry, but I can't find that document, that you mentioned... I just found this link: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYRPW_9.0.1/EnablingAttachmentSecuritySettings.dita, and that one does not say anyhing about "IBM Verse"...

Comment: The documentation does not mention Traveler server, since it was only renamed very recently. It is the same software package as lotus notes traveler though, if a little updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is not missing, it just moved into a sub- menu and documentation is not up to date on that fact.

If you follow your own link to the documentation of IBM Traveler (IBM Verse is the client, the servers' name is still IBM Traveler), there it sais:

> ...navigate to Preferences > Security, and then to either the Apple or
>   Android tab. For Apple devices, select Allow only approved
>   applications and built in secure viewers to access attachments...

This information is outdated, as in newer versions under Apple there are two tabs: `Apple Mail` and `IBM Verse`: The setting can only be found in `Apple Mail`.

For IBM Verse there are other options like `Prohibit export of attachments` and `Prohibit download of attachments`: Not quite the same, but similar. The former is an option available in iOS the latter are options built into IBM Verse app...

You can check the available options [in this Link at IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYRPW_9.0.1/Server_synchronized_settings.dita)

Comment: Is it at all possible to apply a similar restriction to the IBM verse application? I assume this change was made because the IBM verse application did not exist when that documentation was written, right?

Comment: For IBM Verse there are other options like `Prohibit export of attachments` and `Prohibit download of attachments`: Not quite the same, but similar. The former is an option available in iOS the latter are options built into IBM Verse app...